# What rule am I breaking implementing dynamic styles on an Angular 2 component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, flexbox

The desired workflow: A globally provided service (FlexContainer) returns various CSS values that are set on a `div`. A control panel component (AdminPanelCmp) allows a user to select different values for the CSS properties provided by the FlexContainer service, which should change the CSS values on the `div`.

The weird thing is, the styles are being initialized properly and the option selectors are updating their models properly when selected. But the `style` attr just won't update. Since no errors are being thrown, I'm assuming it must be a simple thing... but I can't see it.

Any one see what I'm missing?

Here are the relevant bits of the FlexContainer's component (not the service):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'flex-container',
    template: `
            <div id="flex-container" [ngStyle]="flexContainer.styles | PropsToSelectors" class="flex-container">
            </div>  
    `,
    directives: [NgStyle],
    providers: [FlexContainer],
    pipes: [PropsToSelectors]
})

export class FlexContainerCmp {
    constructor(public flexContainer: FlexContainer) {}
}
```

Now the FlexContainer service:

```
export class FlexContainer {
    public styles: any;
    public styleOptions: any;
    constructor() {
        this.styles = containerDefaults;
        this.styleOptions = containerOptions;
    }
```

}

And the Admin Panel where you adjust the FlexContainer styles:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'admin-panel',
    templateUrl: './components/templates/adminPanel.html',
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
    pipes: [DerpPipe]
})

export class AdminPanelCmp {
    public options: any;
    constructor(public flexContainer: FlexContainer) {
        this.options = containerOptions;
    }

}
```

And the template for the admin panel:

```
<span class="cp-c-title">container properties</span>
    <label>flex-direction:
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="flexContainer.styles.flexDirection">
            <option *ngFor="#opt of flexContainer.styleOptions.flexDirection | derp" [value]="opt">{{opt}}</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <label>flex-wrap:
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="flexContainer.styles.flexWrap">
            <option *ngFor="#opt of flexContainer.styleOptions.flexWrap | derp" [value]="opt">{{opt}}</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <label>justify-content:
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="flexContainer.styles.justifyContent">
            <option *ngFor="#opt of flexContainer.styleOptions.justifyContent | derp" [value]="opt">{{opt}}</option>
        </select>           </label>
    <label>align-items:
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="flexContainer.styles.alignItems">
            <option *ngFor="#opt of flexContainer.styleOptions.alignItems | derp" [value]="opt">{{opt}}</option>
        </select>
        </label>
    <label>align-content:
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="flexContainer.styles.alignContent">
            <option *ngFor="#opt of flexContainer.styleOptions.alignContent | derp" [value]="opt">{{opt}}</option>
        </select>
    </label>
```

Finally, the data that makes it all go around:

```
export var containerOptions = {
    'display': 'flex',
    'width': '100%',
    'height': '100%',
    'flexWrap': ['wrap', 'nowrap'],
    'flexDirection': ['row', 'column'],
    'justifyContent': ['flex-start', 'flex-end', 'center', 'space-between', 'space-around'],
    'alignItems': ['flex-start', 'flex-end', 'center', 'baseline', 'stretch'],
    'alignContent': ['flex-start', 'flex-end', 'center', 'space-between', 'space-around', 'stretch']
};

export var containerDefaults = {
    'display': 'block',
    'width': '100%',
    'height': '100%',
    'flexWrap': 'wrap',
    'flexDirection': 'row',
    'justifyContent': 'center',
    'alignItems': 'center',
    'alignContent': 'center'
};
```

Oh, and the DerpPipe is a workaround to [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6392) in case you're wondering.